# What library to split videos in one file MP4 in C#

Tags: c#, video

I have an application similar Window Media Player
I have one file video MP4 that video have stream front and rear video ( like as Auto camera). I have used element: MediaElement in WPF of C# but it not support well.
So, I can use what library to split video and deploy it on my application easily ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by splitting videos? If I inserted a 5 minute long video.. would this splitting process produce two videos at 2.5 minutes each? Or, are you trying to split the content on the screen in two? Or... are you trying to combine videos?

Comment: Videos are saved following format STREAM. Do you used library for processing video in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're processing media, check out my wrapper of `FFmpeg` called `MediaToolkit`

https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit